# problem with passing objects from array in collection.find()

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mean-stack

I can't seem to figure out how to pass objects from arry in collection.find('{pid: patient[0][i].pid}'). it is a concatenation problem.

```
router.get('/fullsurveys/:doctor', async (request, res) => {
    try{
        const doctor = JSON.parse(request.params.doctor);
        posts = [];
        patients = [];
        patients.push(await Patient.find(doctor));
        for(var i = 0; i < patients[0].length; i++){
            if(patients[0][i].patientstate == true){
                posts.push(await FullSurvey.find('{pid: patient[0][i].pid}'));
            }
        }
        res.json(posts);   
        }catch(err){
        res.json({message: err});
    }
});
```

Comment: What is the question/problem? what is the value of `request.params.doctor`

Comment: [Model.find](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.find) takes an object, not a string

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are passing stringified json in find function & the variable name in FullSuvery.find seems to be wrongs, you have `patient[0][i].pid` when it should have been `patients[0][i].pid`

Change you code to

```
router.get('/fullsurveys/:doctor', async (request, res) => {
    try{
        const doctor = JSON.parse(request.params.doctor);
        posts = [];
        patients = [];
        patients.push(await Patient.find({doctor:doctor}));
        for(var i = 0; i < patients[0].length; i++){
            if(patients[0][i].patientstate == true){
                posts.push(await FullSurvey.find({pid: patients[0][i].pid}));
            }
        }
        res.json(posts);   
        }catch(err){
        res.json({message: err});
    }
})
```